# XML to XML conversion: nesting similar nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<ref>
<m-citation>
<string-name>
<surname>Carey</surname>, <given-names>J.W.</given-names>
</string-name>, <string-name>
<surname>Wigand</surname>, <given-names>M.</given-names>
</string-name>, <string-name>
<surname>Can</surname>, <given-names>S.J.</given-names>
</string-name>,
<year>2007</year>. <source>xyz</source>, <volume>1</volume>, <f>75</f>-<l>85</l>. 
</m-citation>
</ref>
```

Need to convert this to:

```
<ref>
<m-citation>
<publisher>
<name>
<surname>Carey</surname><given-names>J.W.</given-names>
</name>, <name>
<surname>Wigand</surname><given-names>M.</given-names>
</name>, <name>
<surname>Can</surname><given-names>S.J.</given-names>
</name>,
</publisher> 
<year>2007</year>. <source>xyz</source>, <volume>1</volume>, <f>75</f>-<l>85</l>. 
</m-citation>
</ref>
```

Please note: 'string-name' changes to 'name', all 'string-name' elements are nested within 'publisher' element and comma after surname is not retained.
Tried different ways but couldn't get the exact output. Help of any kind would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

I have written the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="m-citation">
<xsl:element name="m-citation">

<xsl:element name="publisher">
<xsl:for-each select="string-name[position() &lt;= last()]">
<xsl:element name="name">
<xsl:element name="surname">
<xsl:value-of select="surname"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="given-names">
<xsl:value-of select="given-names"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>

<xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="ref//year">
<xsl:element name="year">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref//source">
<xsl:element name="source">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Similarly for elements volume, f and l.

I am getting the following output:

```
<ref>
<m-citation>
<publisher>
<name>
<surname>Carey</surname><given-names>J.W.</given-names>
</name>, <name>
<surname>Wigand</surname><given-names>M.</given-names>
</name>, <name>
<surname>Can</surname><given-names>S.J.</given-names>
</name>,
</publisher> ,,,
<year>2007</year>. <source>xyz</source>, <volume>1</volume>, <f>75</f>-<l>85</l>. 
</m-citation>
</ref>
```

as I am using apply-templates the commas after string-name (which are outside all child elements) get displayed (,,,).
Sorry for the errors if any in the above lines of code. Have cut-shortened it here and there.

Comment: You say you tried different ways. Can you share the one that was closest to what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Can you post what you did try? We don't want to suggest areas you have already tested.

Comment: Your examples have quite some issues with closing tags. I guess that is not an issue. As for the XSLT answer: Just match the ref-tag. <copy of-select="anything that did not change"/> and adapt the rest with writing some xml-elements and copying the content of the tag you want to rename.

Comment: Tried the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- At m-citation, put in the publisher element then apply templates to all string-name
       elements, and to all text nodes that have a string-name element after them.
       Outside the publisher element, apply templates to everything else. -->
  <xsl:template match="m-citation">
    <xsl:copy>
      <publisher>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="string-name | text()[count(following-sibling::string-name) &gt; 0]"/>
      </publisher>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::string-name) and count(following-sibling::string-name) = 0]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace string-name with name then apply-templates to its children. -->
  <xsl:template match="string-name">
    <name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </name>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove the first text node that comes after surname (a comma in your particular
       input. -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::surname]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following input XML:

```
<ref>
  <m-citation>
    <string-name>
      <surname>Carey</surname>, <given-names>J.W.</given-names>
    </string-name>, <string-name>
      <surname>Wigand</surname>, <given-names>M.</given-names>
    </string-name>, <string-name>
      <surname>Can</surname>, <given-names>S.J.</given-names>
    </string-name>
    <year>2007</year>. <source>xyz</source> <volume>1</volume> <f>75</f> <l>85</l>.
    </m-citation>
</ref>
```

produces the following output:

```
<ref>
  <m-citation><publisher>
    <name>
      <surname>Carey</surname><given-names>J.W.</given-names>
    </name>, <name>
      <surname>Wigand</surname><given-names>M.</given-names>
    </name>, <name>
      <surname>Can</surname><given-names>S.J.</given-names>
    </name></publisher>
    <source>xyz</source> <volume>1</volume> <f>75</f> <l>85</l>.
  </m-citation>
</ref>
```

which is not *quite* formatted as you want, but I think the content is all there correctly.

Comment: This is what I wanted. Just needed to ask you what if we don't know what element would occur after "</publisher>". It could not necessarily be "year".

Comment: So is the rule that `<publisher>` should appear after the last `name` element?

Comment: The last `name` element should end with `</publisher>` which is absolutely fine. But the next element may not necessarily be `year` (as per your code). `Source`, `volume` or for that matter any valid element may occur after the end of `publisher`.

Comment: I've changed the stylesheet accordingly. Please give it a go. Now it only puts elements up to and including the last `<name>` element inside `<publisher>`.

Answer (score 0):

With the next XSLT the element `string-name` will be translated into `name` and a `publisher` element will be added. All other elements and values are copied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="m-citation">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <publisher>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="string-name" />
            </publisher>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::string-name)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="string-name">
        <name>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </name>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not retaining the punctuations I guess:           <xsl:apply-templates select="year | volume | fpage | lpage" />

Comment: If you change that into `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::string-name)]" />`, it will preserve the punctation

Comment: Same issue as in my code. The commas after string-name getting displayed as well. In this case ",,,".